# Excel, returning what's not equal when comparing columns

Tags: excel

I have a few columns for example:

```
a   b   c
1   1   0
1   1   0
0   1   0
```

So I can easily find out if they are equal or not (row 1 = row 2):

`=and(a2=a3,b2=b3,c2=c3)`

When doing this for comparing row 2 to row 3 we get `FALSE`, however I'd like to know a way to find out which column(s) caused the fail.  In this case it would return column a.

EDIT

I guess I could check each column individually and then search for `FALSE`'s on that row of results, but seeking something more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I got one for you. This formula is for matching `ROW 1` and `ROW 2` of your sample data.

```
=IF(AND(A1=A2,B1=B2,C1=C2),"Matched","Unmatched Column: " & IF((A1=A2),"","A") & IF((B1=B2),"","B") & IF((C1=C2),"","C"))
```

If you want to matched more than two row, don't worry, put that formula in first row and drag the cell value to the last row. So, every row will filled with related formulas.

I think that the another way is making with `excel-vba` and no more way to do. If you found the other way, post it. We will vote.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! May I ask how the colon works in this situation as the rest makes sense

Comment: I am not clearly understand your question. Sorry, can you tell more.

Comment: Ive just never used a : within a formula other than to define a range eg A1:A10

Comment: Colon ":" in my formula is nothing. It is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use conditional formatting.

Highlight the range A3:C4, Choose Conditional Formatting | New Rule | Use a formula... and enter

```
=A2<>A3
```

then choose a format (e.g. fill colour) to highlight the cells that don't match.

The formula automatically changes to =A3<>A4 for the second and third rows of data, so will highlight cell A4.